# Protracor tests slow down with increase in specs

Tags: protractor

As I  keep on increasing the no. of tests in my specs and when I start running my tests. They run at a quick pace but after certain time all my tests start to run very slowly.

I am new to protractor can anyone help me solve this problem.

Comment: Can you give us few more details? to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling CSS Animations and Angular Animations to help speed up the Test Suite. Add the following code in the `onPrepare` in your "conf.js" file.

```
...
onPrepare: function() {
    var disableNgAnimate = function() {
        angular
            .module('disableNgAnimate', [])
            .run(['$animate', function($animate) {
                $animate.enabled(false);
            }]);
    };

    var disableCssAnimate = function() {
        angular
            .module('disableCssAnimate', [])
            .run(function() {
                var style = document.createElement('style');
                style.type = 'text/css';
                style.innerHTML = '* {' +
                    '-webkit-transition: none !important;' +
                    '-moz-transition: none !important' +
                    '-o-transition: none !important' +
                    '-ms-transition: none !important' +
                    'transition: none !important' +
                    '}';
                document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
            });
    };

    browser.addMockModule('disableNgAnimate', disableNgAnimate);
    browser.addMockModule('disableCssAnimate', disableCssAnimate);
}
...
```